# Elixir/Phoenix System cmd to start server

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I've made a release with Distillery, so I can start it with `./bin/app start`, now I'm trying to start it with elixir, like this:

```
path = "/Users/user/app/0.0.1/bin/"
System.cmd("./app", ["start"], cd: path)
```

But unfortunately, get `:enoent` error. I guess it is because `./app` is not really a command, but a file. So, my question is, whether it is possible to make it work with `System.cmd`?

I tried with `Enum.join([executable, "start"], " ") |> String.to_char_list |> :os.cmd`, but this method won't provide errors, if they happen. So I would prefer to archive same, but with `System.cmd`.

Any advise appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Try `System.cmd(Path.join(path, "app"), ["start"], cd: path)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.cmd/3` expects an absolute path to the executable if the executable is not in a directory present in `PATH`:

> `command` is expected to be an executable available in PATH unless an absolute path is given.

Your application's directory is most likely not in PATH, so you can instead pass the absolute path to the app like this:

```
System.cmd(Path.join(path, "app"), ["start"], cd: path)
```

Comment: Hey @Dogbert, I've managed to get it work with your suggestion. Thank you!